# CONCAT_WS not working on select statement

Tags: activerecord, yii2

Im trying to concatenate "firstname" and "lastname" like this "firstname lastname"
while doing a search query.

here's my code:

```
$query = Contact::find()
    ->select([
        "CONCAT_WS(' ', firstname, lastname) AS name"
    ])
    ->where('(firstname like :fname) OR (lastname like :lname) OR (email = :email)', [
        ':fname' => $searchkey,
        ':lname' => $searchkey,
        ':email' => $searchkey,
    ])->all();
```

but the result is empty like this:

```
Array
(
   [0] => common\models\contact\Contact Object
   (
        [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => 
        [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
            (
            )

   )

)
```

I'm expecting that i'll have something like this

```
[name] => "firstname lastname"
```

output but no luck. need help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should  add  a **public var $name** in your Contcat  model and add attribute as **safe** in rules  for recive the calculated value  with alias name

```
class Contact extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{

  public $name;
  .... 

}
```

Comment: I've tried what you said but still no luck. I actually have two models `Contact` and `ContactQuery`. `ContactQuery` is where I've put your suggested codes because that's where my function for search resides.

Comment: Sorry it actually does work `[name] => testfirstname lastname` this is the output,
`[_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array()` how can I place it inside the _atttributes or is it impossible?

Comment: I don't understand your last comment .. please explain better your need

Comment: Current output is like this
`[name] => testfirstname lastname`
`[_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array()`
what i want is like this
`[_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array(`
 `[name] => testfirstname lastname)` if this is possible.

Comment: You are using a concat_ws  and the result for this is not an array but a string ..